# Hacer un SELECT con los campos del checkbox

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy intentando que se imprima por consola los campos seleccionados de un checkbox, pero no lo consigo.
Estoy utilizando NodeJs con los módulos de express, http, lodash, mysql y body-parser.

En el `front-end` tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
<form method="post" action="selectDb">
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tbl" value="nom">Nombre
    <input type="checkbox" name='tbl' value="ape">Apellido
    <input type="checkbox" name='tbl' value="s_a">Segundo apellido
</div>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Enviar">

</form>
```

Lo cual responde en el `back-end` a lo siguiente:

```
// POST SELECT
app.post('/selectDb', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const body = _.pick(req.body, ['tbl'])
        console.log(body.tbl);

//SELECT
pool.query('SELECT ' + body.tbl +' FROM Pruebas'), function(error, result){
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
}

        res.sendfile('./index.html')

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).json({
            ERROR: `Something wend wrong and err is ${e}.`
        })
    }
});
```

¿Cómo consigo hacer la `query` correctamente?

**[EDIT]**

He intentado probar algo más, pero también me genera error:

```
// POST SELECT
app.post('/selectDb', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const body = _.pick(req.body, ['tbl'])
        console.log(body.tbl);
        var selNom = body.tbl[0];
        var selApe = body.tbl[1];
        var selSAp = body.tbl[2];

        console.log(selNom +' '+ selApe +' '+ selSAp);

//SELECT
pool.query('SELECT '+selNom+' '+selApe+' '+selSAp+' FROM Pruebas', function(error, result){
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
});

        res.sendfile('./index.html')

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).json({
            ERROR: `Something wend wrong and err is ${e}.`
        })
    }
});
```

Añadí como variables los valores sacados de body.tbl[0,1,2]
El problema es el siguiente:

1. No funciona
2. Si por ejemplo solamente selecciono UN solo campo en el checkbox, por ejemplo Nombre, su valor correspondiente en el formulario es nom, sacaría como valor [0]=n, como valor [1]=o y como valor [2]=m
3. Genera un error enorme al parsearlo:

```
/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 's_a FROM Pruebas' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    --------------------
    at Pool.query (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:199:23)
    at app.post (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/server.js:83:6)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
```

Comment: el name para tus checkbox es igual para todos, pero no es un arreglo intenta con `name="tbl[]"` no obstante deverias validar que sea un arreglo para evitar este tipo de errores....

Comment: Ya probé con name = tbl[] y nada, lo explico en el EDIT